# How to clip a Polyhedron using a plane in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, computational-geometry

I want to split a parent convex polyhedron (3D) using a plane (2D) into 2 child closed convex polyhedrons. How to do this in Python3? An illustrative example is shown in image below.

[image]

Comment: There would be multiple ways to do this, depending on how you choose to represent your polyhedron in Python as variables. From the image, I get exactly what you are trying to do, but to get a good answer here, you need to get started on your problem on your own first. The community can then help you with questions related to the specific Python-errors you encounter along the way.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your polyhedron is represented as a vertex/edge/face graph, you can

- classify the vertices as belonging to one half-space or the other,
- keep all edges and faces wholly on the same side,
- create new vertices where an edge crosses the plane (such edges join two vertices on a different side),
- restore the topology of the faces that are split, by linking the two intersection points by new edges.